# OLS restricting access per IP

Tags: openlitespeed

I want to restrict the access to my phpmyadmin folder so it could be accessible only by 1 IP.

I've already done that successfully for the domains hosted on the server using the following rewrite rules, as per the documentation:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.234\.455\.566
RewriteRule ^/phpmyadmin/.*$ - [F,L]
```

However, I can still access it using the server's IP, like that:

xx.xx.xx.xx/phpmyadmin

What would be the best approach to fix this?

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin/.*$ - [F,L]`  , restart OLS

Comment: nop, it doesn't work. i can still access it from the server's ip xx.xx.xx.xx/phpmyadmin

Comment: if you do `RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin/.*$ - [F,L]` alone , without rewritecond , does it work ?

Comment: If I do that I'm still able to access the phpmyadmin folder from 12.34.56.78/phpmyadmin

Comment: go to webadmin console, virtual host -> context , see if you have a phpmyadmin context , and control it from there